# Values for which the linear map is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have some confusion about injective linear maps and can't get help anywhere. My book says that:

Let $T$ be a linear map $T:V \rightarrow W$ then $T$ is injective if and only if $kerl(T) = 0$. That means two different elements under $T$ should have two different images.

Now this a confusing part for me:

When we write $T(V) = W$ then we mean that we multiply input vectors $v \in V$ with some matrix(transformation matrix) then we get an output-vector/image $(w \in W)$.

$(1):$ What I understood is that the kernel of the transformation matrix should be $0$  but what happens if the kernel of $T$(which I assume is a matrix) is $0$ but the input vector-vector ($v \in V$) are linearly dependent? Is that still an injective linear map?

$(2)$ Suppose I'm given a linear map $T:V \rightarrow W$ where

${ \{v_1 = (1, 2, -2), v_2 = (3, 6, -4),  v_3 =(0,1,a^2-1)}\} \in V$

and

$\{w_1 = (2,-a^2,-1) ,w_2 = (4, 6-2a, 2), w_3 = (0, 3, 2)\} \in W$

I was asked for which values of $a$ there is **at least one** injective linear map such that $T(v_1) = w_1 ,T(v_2) = w_2,T(v_3) = w_3$

and for which values there is a **unique injective linear** map.

Here I'm not given the transformation matrix $T$ but only the input-vector and images, so how do i determine when there is at least one injective linear map?

I only need hint/(if possible steps with explanation if possible) and not full solution.

Comment: What do you mean by **input vector-vector (v∈V) are linearly dependent**

Comment: You should be careful to distinguish between *sets* of vectors and individual vectors at this stage of learning.  For example, the kernel of $T$ is a set of vectors, not an individual vector.  So we say the kernel is $\{0\}$ when $T$ is injective, i.e. the kernel is a set that contains only the zero vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the definitions: an injective map is a map that does not map any two different elements to the same element. This is in general. For the specific case of linear maps, you can prove that it is equivalent to not mapping any non-zero element to $0$, which in turn is equivalent to $\ker(T)=\{0\}$.

If you write $T(V)=W$, then you actually mean that the map $T$ is surjective, since for every $w \in W$ there is $v \in V$ such that $T(v)=w$. If you don't intend $T$ to be surjective, you should just write $T \colon V \to W$ (or $T(V) \subseteq W$).

(1) your question is not clear: being injective is a property of the map, it does not depend on the input vectors you choose. But if the map is injective, then linearly independent vectors in $V$ are mapped to linearly independent vectors in $W$ (can you see why this is so?). Linearly dependent vectors are always mapped to linearly dependent vectors, even if $T$ is not injective (can you see why?)

(2) if linearly independent vectors are mapped to linearly dependent vectors, then there can be no injective map that does it, as we have seen in (1). If on the other hand all the $v_i$ are linearly independent, then they form a basis (you know why?), so their images (if they are linearly independent) determine a unique injective linear map. If the $v_i$ are linearly dependent, then you have to see whether it is possible to define a map with the required properties and whether it is injective or not. It is difficult to say more, not knowing which facts you can use.

Comment: i forgot to write dimension of $V$ and $W$ both have same dimension that's why I wrote $T(V) = W$. As you said being injective is property of map(in this case of $T$) so how do i tell if $T(V) = W$ is injective? because $T(V) = A.V$ and what is my $A$?

Comment: Even if $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension (which is clear, since their vectors all have 3 coordinates), it does not mean that $T$ is surjective, so you cannot write $T(V)=W$ in general. It is a fact, though, that if they have the same dimension, $T$ is injective if and only if it is surjective. But I am not sure that you have seen this in class

Comment: @Khan Saab What is $A$? I guess the image of $T$?

Comment: Thanks, Now i think i understand, If all vectors of $W$ are linearly independent then i have atleast one linearly injective map and if all vectors of $V$ are linearly independent then i have a unique linearly independent map.

Comment: Wait, it's not completely correct. I'll write LI and LD for linearly (in)dependent. Sorry for the sloppy notation. In general: V LI and W LD: no injective map. V LI and W LI: one injective map. V LD and W LI: no map at all. V LD and W LD: in some cases there is one (or several) injective map(s). In your specific case, it seems to me (I have not checked carefully) that V LI always and W LD only for $a=0,1$. So in those two cases there is no injective map, in the other cases a unique one. But as I said, I have not checked carefully.

Comment: The above holds in the case where both $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension and this corresponds to the amount of vectors given. Note that "V LI" means that the vectors are LI, not that V is, which would make no sense